# jQuery Random Link Color on Hover

Tags: jquery, css

The script below works perfectly. However, it's not quite what I'm trying to achieve. I'd like to have 'on hover' it to pick 1 color and stay on it instead of cycling through all the colors per link on hover. You can see the example of the effect I don't want here http://www.morxmedia.com/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  original = $('.menu-item a').css('color');
  $('.menu-item a').hover(function() { //mouseover
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
 if(rand == 0){var col = '#EAD325';}
 else if(rand == 1){var col = '#FE902F';}
 else if(rand == 2){var col = '#82BE38';}
 else if(rand == 3){var col = '#217AFC';}
 else{var col = '#888888';}

    $(this).animate({'color': col,});
  },function() { //mouseout
    $(this).animate({
      'color': original,
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generates a random color for each link, saves it into an array. On hover it checks what color it should be, and animates to it.

See working example: http://jsfiddle.net/fRqj2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var assignedColors = new Array();

    $('.menu-item a').each(function(i) {
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
        if (rand == 0) {
            var col = '#EAD325';
        }
        else if (rand == 1) {
            var col = '#FE902F';
        }
        else if (rand == 2) {
            var col = '#82BE38';
        }
        else if (rand == 3) {
            var col = '#217AFC';
        }
        else {
            var col = '#888888';
        }
        assignedColors[i] = col;
    });

    original = $('.menu-item a').css('color');
    $('.menu-item a').hover(function() { //mouseover
        index = $(this).parent().prevAll().length;
        $(this).animate({
            'color': assignedColors[index]
        });
    }, function() { //mouseout
        $(this).animate({
            'color': original,
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! However, it doesn't seem to be randomizing the colors on jsfiddle.

Comment: It works here. We agree that it should only update the color on page reload right? Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/fRqj2/1/ - updaing it should post the random colors to an alert :)

Comment: Hmm, well I just tested it live, and this maybe the issue with the other code I was using.. It seems to have a random color and fade into another random color you can see here: http://morxmedia.com/ I'm using your code

Comment: Its the `themes/mm/library/js/scripts.js` that makes the weird behaviour. See this example where i removed it: http://jsfiddle.net/fRqj2/5/embedded/result/

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I wonder why the contents of that file would cause that. But it's working now, and exactly the result I was expecting! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You could mark the color to the element with [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/). Something like this:

```
  ...
  col = $(this).data("hoverColor"); // Tries to load the color for the element
  if (! col ) {
    col = getRandomColor();
    $(this).data("hoverColor", col ); // Saves the color for the element
  }
  ...
```

Comment: I'm not very efficient with JavaScript. I'm best with html/css and graphic design haha. Can you rewrite this in a way that I can copy and paste with the colors I listed? I'd really appreciate it. :)